# Vue.js Bootstrap table - How to extract IDs of table rows and collect them in a data property

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-table

I'm using Vue.js Bootstrap table and I would like to be able to collect each table row id in an Array or Object data property.

Here is an example of a bootstrap table template:

```
      <template v-slot:cell(label)="row" >
        <div >
          <div class="label"></div>
        </div>
      </template>
```

So, how can I collect `row.item.id` values in an Array or in an Object in order to use this data for other purposes?

Comment: As you are binding the data to the bootstrap table. You can simply get the id's from each object by using `Array.map()` method from the source data object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store any property from the items array into a separate array by iterating using Array.map() method.

For example **:**

```
data() {
  return {
    items: [
      { id: 1, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
      { id: 2, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
      { id: 3, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
      { id: 4, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
    ],
    itemsID: []
  }
}
```

Then in mounted hook **:**

```
mounted() {
    this.itemsID = this.items.map(({id}) => id)
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a computed property, it is usually more robust than a one-time call in a lifecycle hook

Comment: @MoritzRingler Yeah that will also work, I just gave a suggestion to achieve that. At the end it depends on PO how they want to utilize this.